# User-rotatable elements in the browser

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I'm creating something which requires the end user to move objects around using his mouse, change their size and rotate the object. Most of this can be achieved using something like JqueryUI [(here)](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) except rotating. I need the user to be able to rotate objects.

One option is to put a slider which adjusts the CSS transform properties, but if there's a way to do this in a more intuitive way (a la powerpoint/photoshop) it would be great.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1/ is another solution using a drag able handle.

```
// Your original element
var ele = $('#selector');

$('#selector').draggable({});

// Create handle dynamically
$('<div></div>').appendTo(ele).attr('id','handle').css({
'position': 'absolute',
'bottom': 5,
'right': 5,
'height': 10,
'width': 10,
'background-color': 'orange'
});

ele.css('position', 'relative');

$('#handle').draggable({
handle: '#handle',
opacity: 0.01, 
helper: 'clone',
drag: function(event, ui){
    var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

    $(this).parent().css({
        '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
        '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/38ZsD/

It is a mixture of JS and CSS to do what you want.

```
$('.rotate').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('rotated');
```

});

And use the transform class in CSS